# Saving number as text, how to automate it

Tags: vba, excel

I have a `7702216772` number inside a cell. If I put a `'` before the fist digit and click `Enter` `Excel` transforms the number to a text and puts a green triangle at the left top of the cell:

[image]

I have many rows of similar numbers all of which need to be transformed into text. However clicking each and adding `'` before the first symbol and clicking `Enter` would take a lot of time. Is there any way to do it programatically?

I tried using formula: `="'"&H4` but it doesn't do what's expected - the green triangle never appears on the result cell.

**I also tried setting cell format to Text, but the green triangle doesn't appear in that case too.**

**I need the green triangle to appear at the upper left corner, just like at the picture!**

Comment: Is this a mobile number which is dropping the 0 at the start? Because if so just change the column to Text value before pasting.

Comment: In cell G4 put formula `=H4&""` and copy down as much as you need. `Copy >> Paste Special >> Values` should give you what you need.

Comment: @Kyoujin The first digit is not zero. I tried changing column to text, doesn't work. While it says the column's format is Text the pasted numbers lack green trianle at the upper left corner.

Answer (score 2):

If all your number are in a single column, the following code will do it:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = "'" & ws.Cells(i, "A").Value 'add the ' before the number
Next i
End Sub
```

Change the "A" to whichever column you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Just `Select` the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub Textify()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(2, 1)
    For Each r In rng
        r.Value = "'" & r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Non VBA answer; I'm using Column G in this answer but it depends on where your numbers are. You'll have to change the cell but I think you will be ok with this.

- In an empty cell, enter formula: `="'"&G4`
- Use the fill handle or `Ctrl+D` to fill it down to the length of Column G's values.
- Select the whole of Column G's values and copy them to the clipboard
- Select the same range in Column G, right-click, select `Paste Special` and choose `Values`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it now for several times and it worked always

```
Cells(xx, xx).FormulaR1C1 = "'" & Cells(xx, xx).Value
```

Same would work for ActiveCell or whatever you like.